# Intercept traffic in BURP using reqwest Rust

Tags: rust, proxy, reqwest

I'm trying to learn rust and getting started building a system using `Reqwest` libary, but I would to analyse how the request is being created using BURP, so I created this code:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), reqwest::Error> {

           
    let client = reqwest::Client::builder().proxy(reqwest::Proxy::http("http://127.0.0.1:8080")?).build()?;

    let resp = client.get("https://httpbin.org/ip").send().await;


    println!("{resp:#?}");
    Ok(())
}
```

At first, the request is sent and printable the output but I can't intercept the traffic, Is it anything missing it?